# Play not compiling the project

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I created my play project successfully, but when i use     **play run**     its showing exception

```
[info] Loading project definition from H:\MyPlay\project
H:\MyPlay\build.sbt:8: error: ')' expected but eof found.
cache
   ^
[error] Error parsing expression.  Ensure that there are no blank lines within a
setting.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
[warn] Ignoring load failure: no project loaded.
[error] Not a valid command: run
[error] run
[error]    ^
```

Help me please, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, You are using any whitespace or new line in your build.sbt file

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 jdbc,
 anorm,
  cache


 )
```

change it with

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 jdbc,
 anorm,
  cache  
  )
```

this should solve your problem

Comment: I'll take care of it. BTW thnks